# Should popular tutorials get their own tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently I noticed the [donut](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donut) tag had been created. Initially, I was a bit unsure about having a tag like this; it seems like one of the first 'non-technical' tags and I wasn't sure whether there was a point to it. I understand there are a lot of [donut questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=donut) that further categorisation *could* be useful, but do the other tags available not correctly describe what those questions are *about*, be it modelling, rendering or particles? If people asked a lot of question about rigging humans, would we really need a [human](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human) tag when we have a [rigging](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rigging) tag?

I understand the [donut](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donut) tag doesn't *necessarily* reference a specific tutorial, but I think we're all aware it really is just Blender Guru's tutorials generating these questions. Personally, if we *were* to tag such questions then I would prefer to tag them as [donut-tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donut-tutorial) to make it clear we are referring to a specific tutorial and not just using a synonym for a torus and not just naming something that happens to be in the question. That also begs the question as to whether other tutorials (Blender Guru's [Anvil](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=anvil) tutorial comes to mind) could *also* do with categorisation or whether existing tags are satisfactory?

My questions are:

- Do we need a [donut](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donut) tag?
- Should the tag be renamed to [donut-tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donut-tutorial)?
- Should other tutorials (I can currently only think of the Anvil one) also get their own tags?

I'm not specifically against this new tag, I just wanted to make sure we have some kind of consensus before I retag old questions I come across.

Comment: It could be more logical to have "tutorial" tag to get them all under one roof. Other than that I didn't think any of tutorials deserve specific tags for them since after all they are about the same problems covered by usual tags

Comment: Not the bloody anvil again...

Comment: Further to  @MrZak above  could perhaps `blender-guru` (or some such) encompass all tutorials from that popular site. A popular addon can get its own tag outside the umbrella of `addons` tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NO, no, no and no. It is a useless categorization for BSE. A of [donut](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donut) tells us nothing about the question, except that the OP is probably following Price's tutorial - not really helpful for us. Each tag should be able to tell us what the question is about, (examples: [modifiers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modifiers), [rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendering), [animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation)) not how the OP got to the point of asking that question.

For example when we get a Z fighting question we do not care what the OP is modeling, it could be an anvil, a watch, a spaceship, a submarine, etc (all tutorials we have gotten question from) nor do we care what tutorial the OP was following. The question is about Z fighting, period.

If I ask a question tagged [eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eevee) you know I'm using eevee. Or if a question is tagged [shadowcatcher](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowcatcher) we know it is about the [shadow catcher](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/object_settings/object_data.html).

I am definitely against adding tutorial tags. The *only* possible benefit would be that it could make finding dups easier, but that is not a valid reason to make a useless tag.

So please nuke any tutorial inspired tags as they pop up.

Donuts are great, everybody likes them, we will always take questions about making them, but we do not need a [image] tag.

---

PS sadly this is not the first 'non-technical' tag, see [error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error), [artifacts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artifacts), [effects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effects), [lego](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego) and other ambiguous tags that should be cleaned up [actions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actions), [splines](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splines), [loop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop), [looping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looping), [project](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project) (used as both a "blender project" and "UV project modifier").

Comment: Other confusing tags are "blender-render", "image".

Answer (score 3):

I don't particularly care for the name of the tag. Nor do I believe that all videos deserve a tag. But this particular so called "tutorial" generates a lot of repeated questions.

**What are tags anyway?**

As defined here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer **by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories**.

I created a tag to make it easier to find duplicates and point the users to an existing and approved answer or detailed post, as opposed to having users write the same answer over and over, or have search for endless other solutions spanned over many posts.

Note that finding duplicates is not as easy or straightforward as it seems. The **search** box at the top has many shortcomings, it won't deal with synonym or related terms... and if any of the search terms or text on the post is misspelled o slightly different, then the results won't show at all.

I believe a tag in this case will make it easier to **get the users to the information they are looking for**. Isn't that the goal of this site?

Comment: Internal BSE search indeed isn't the best one. I always use google search instead by typing in there BSE domain name and then my query

Comment: Maybe it will change it future, but based on David's answer I think we should stick to more technical tags for the minute. Most of the 'donut' questions seem to mention donut in the question body, so using the search box would find those questions without the need for the tag. (Happy to deal with removing the tag from questions if you would like.)

Comment: @RayMairlot Don't worry I'm done with the site too.

Comment: Because of this discussion? I of course did not mean any of this personally and didn't think it was being taken this way. You're obviously an incredibly valuable member of this SE community.

Comment: @RayMairlot of course not, or anything related to you. I'm just moving on. will use the current circumstances to phase out. It was fun...

Comment: Seems a lot of questions here get tasked here because of Blender Guru's tutorials, and Andrew Price doesn't have to field the questions of his own audience. I was looking for a way to keep track of them and then sort (use the BSE search) to then point them out to him and ask him to take a stab at answering them. I figured using a tag was the best way, but that got reversed per this thread here. Any suggestions to still try to make list, or not a possibility?